# Skip Link Goes to Sticky Navigation Instead of Content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, zurb-foundation, accessibility, sticky

Hello all I am trying to build a web accessible WordPress site with [Foundation by Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) using a starter theme called JointsWP. The site is located at, http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/ I created a sticky navigation that sticks to the top but when you scroll down the page it changes to a navigation button when hovered over or selected it reveals the full navigation that is shown when at the top of the page.

Bellow is the markup of the Navigation:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
    <div data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0;" data-sticky-on="small" style="width:100%">
        <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="top-bar-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
          <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
          <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
        </div>

        <div class="top-bar psad-nav" id="top-bar-menu">
            <div class="top-bar-left show-for-medium">

    <a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3">
        <img class="logo" src="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/wp-content/themes/JointsWP-CSS-master/assets/images/psad_logo.png" alt="PSAD Logo" style="width:200px;height:200px;" >
    </a>

            </div>
            <div class="top-bar-right">
                <ul id="menu-menu" class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="accordion medium-dropdown"><li id="menu-item-932" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-932 active"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-933"><a href="#">About PSAD</a>
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-914" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-914"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/">Mission and History</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-924" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-924"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/bylaws/">Bylaws</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-913" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-913"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/officers-committees/">Officers</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-925" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-925"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/meeting-minutes/">Meeting Minutes</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-916" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-916"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/psad-hall-rules/">PSAD Hall Rules</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-917" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-917"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/meetingevent-hall-rental-information/">Meeting/Event Hall Rental</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-934" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-934"><a href="#">Get Involved!</a>
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-920" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-920"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/get-involved/">How to Get Involved</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-923" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-923"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/committees/">Committees</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-935" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-935"><a href="#">Programs</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-915" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-915"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/programs/">Programs</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-928" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-928"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/programs/asl-club/">ASL Club</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-930" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-930"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/programs/movie-nights/">Movie Nights</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-931" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-931"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/reunion/">Evergreen State Public/State Schools and Colleges Deaf/HH Reunions</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-929" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-929"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/get-involved/meetings/">Meetings</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-921" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-921"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-926" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-926"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/links/">Links/Resources</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-918" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-918"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/about-psad/newsletters/">Historical Newsletters</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-927" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-927"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/donate/">Donate</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-936" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-936"><a href="#">Membership</a>
<ul class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-911" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-911"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/become-a-member/">Become a Member</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-922" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-922"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/member-reward-points/">Member Reward Points</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-910" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-910"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-912" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-912"><a href="http://twps.psadeaf.org/v3/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
</ul>            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="psad-nav-button hide expanded"  aria-hidden="true">
            <button class="expanded button" type="button">
                ^ Navigation ^
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bellow is the jQuery used for the Navigation scrolling effect:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var psad_scroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    var psad_nav = jQuery( ".psad-nav" );
    var psad_nav_button = jQuery( ".psad-nav-button" );

    function psad_show_nav() {
        if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast( "medium" )) {
            psad_nav.show();
            psad_nav_button.addClass( "hide" ) ;
        }
    }

    function psad_hide_nav() {
        if (Foundation.MediaQuery.atLeast( "medium" )) {
            psad_nav_button.removeClass( "hide" );
            psad_nav.hide();
        }
    }

    if (psad_scroll >= 30) {
        psad_hide_nav();
        psad_nav_button.on({
            click: psad_show_nav,
            mouseenter: psad_show_nav
        });

    }
    if (psad_scroll < 30) {
        psad_show_nav();
    }
});
```

Now my issue is I have created skip links that go to the site Navigation and Main content of the page. Now when selecting the skip link it takes me to the Navigation button that pops up when scrolling down to selected section, instead of selecting the section that the button links to. This means the screen reader reads the Navigation button that sticks to the top instead of the content that was selected in the skip link. I tried adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the button and containing div with no success. How can I get around this issue while keeping the sticky navigation?

Below is the markup of the skip links at the top of the body content:

```
<div id="psad-skip-links" class="expanded" role="navigation" aria-label="Skip Links">
    <a class="show-on-focus expanded button" href="#menu-menu-1">Skip to Navigation</a>
    <a class="show-on-focus expanded button" href="#main">Skip to Content</a>
</div>
```